# Filter duplicates in a BibTeX (.bib) file, like "uniq" for text files?

Tags: bibtex, bibtool

I have a `foo.bib` file containing duplicate entries, and I want to get a file containing the same entries, but without the duplicates. What tool can I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [bibtool](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/bibtool.pdf) tool has an option `-d` designed exactly for that (although it may be hard to find by keywords because the documentation doesn't talk about "duplicate" but about "doubles"):

```
$ cat foo.bib 
@InProceedings{foo19,
  author =       {foo},
  title =        {bar}
}
@InProceedings{foo19,
  author =       {foo},
  title =        {bar}
}
$ bibtool -d foo.bib -o foo-nodup.bib
*** BibTool WARNING: Possible double entries discovered: 
***     foo19 =?= foo19
***     foo19
$ cat foo-nodup.bib 

@InProceedings{   foo19,
  author        = {foo},
  title         = {bar}
}

###InProceedings{ foo19,
  author        = {foo},
  title         = {bar}
}
```

By default, entries are only commented-out. You can strip them completely with `bibtool -- 'print.deleted.entries = off' -d`:

```
$ bibtool -- 'print.deleted.entries = off' -d foo.bib -o foo-nodup.bib
*** BibTool WARNING: Possible double entries discovered: 
***     foo19 =?= foo19
***     foo19
$ cat foo-nodup.bib                                                   

@InProceedings{   foo19,
  author        = {foo},
  title         = {bar}
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to only print duplicates and strip the rest?